# Is it bad to put 3.7V on 3V mice?

Tags: voltage, lithium-ion

I have mouse that take two AAA batteris, so it take 3V.

Is it OK put one 10440 of 3.7V and one spacer instead?

Comment: Probably not... But maybe yes. Depends on how the mouse was designed. How could we know?

Comment: Try it and see whether it smokes. If it does, no. You could make a special spacer containing a series silicon diode for 0.7v drop. It still wouldn't be very clever, because I'll bet the mouse will work down to maybe 2.5, perhaps even 2v, which would damage your 10440 through undervoltage if you let the mouse tell you when it was low.

Comment: I wonder why would you want to do this? Batteries are cheap.

Comment: @Neil_UK
Where can I buy such spacer...?

Comment: @dim
In general is 0.7V difference is really potential to destroy things?

Comment: 0.7V is 23% of the nominal.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How much percent is considered as big difference?

Comment: More than a specified tolerance is considered big. And I don't see a reason for a consumer electronic device powered from battery to have the tolerance more than +/-5%.

Comment: @Dubon The fact is: nobody can give a definitive  answer. We didn't design the mouse.

Comment: The information @EugeneSh. wrote is enough.

Comment: @EugeneSh. if your mouse stops working at nominal cell voltage -5%, it will only use about 10% of the energy in the battery at best ( looking at the 100mA curve at http://www.powerstream.com/AA-tests.htm ). Also many devices are designed to allow Ni-* rechargeables to be used, which start at 20% below nominal. Though I'd agree that there are fewer reasons to have such a wide range above nominal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a fresh alkaline cell would typically have an open circuit reading of a little more than 1.5v leading to a series pair producing more than 3v, this would never be as high as 3.7v in practice.

You'll also find that your 3.7v cell is actually closer to 4.2v when fully charged.

Although it's possible that the designers of your mouse used ICs with a wide voltage range, it's very unlikely as this would probably be more expensive.

As such you'll probably find that your mouse's max operating voltage is 3.3v and *might* survive a short term peak of up to 3.6v.

So your 3.7v nominal (4.2v peak) lithium cell is very likely to do some damage - don't do it.

Comment: Batteries do not force current. The circuit will only draw the voltage it needs. I think the real danger is a potential lack of overdraw protection when using a Li-ion battery

Comment: @Yorik - Your phrase "draw the voltage it needs"  makes no sense. Load circuits draw current, not voltage. Voltage is determined by the source supplying it. Current is what is drawn by the load. Semiconductors have maximum voltage ratings because exceeding breaks down internal oxide insulating layers.

Comment: I think also the Vdd max is rated for shoothru currents  as RdsON reduces with rising Vgs=Vdd and 3.6V logic is 12 to 50 ohms at 3V depending on chip, also the secondary storage voltage of 4.2 quickly drops to 3.8 under load for 100% SoC